# Get values of checkbox controls in sub records page

Tags: c#, checkbox, selection

How can I get selected values of checkbox controls in sub records page?

```
int missingCellValue = missingcell.ToInteger;
int irrelevantCellValue = irrelevantCell.ToInteger;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add more code and explain your question. A general answer to this question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < action.RecordsCount(); i++)
        {
            RetrievalRecord uiRecord = action.GetRecord(i);
            Action_v_Record dbRecord = uiRecord.DataRecord as Action_v_Record;
            CheckboxRetrievalCell missingcell = uiRecord.GetCell(action.missingAction) as CheckboxRetrievalCell;
            CheckboxRetrievalCell irrelevantCell = uiRecord.GetCell(action.irrelevantAction) as CheckboxRetrievalCell;

            int missingCellValue = missingcell.ToInteger;
            int irrelevantCellValue = irrelevantCell.ToInteger;

            dbRecord.Missing.NewValue = missingCellValue;
            dbRecord.irrelevant.NewValue = irrelevantCellValue;

            dbRecord.Update();
        }
```

Please let me know if this works